# How to handle session storage when using html form for login page

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, session

So I was under the impression that it's normal practice to use an html form for your login page and use the action attribute to send your request to the server. But I'm running into trouble with this approach. Specifically, if the login is successful, I don't know how to get access to a session ID on the client side. I would like to receive a response from the server in some way so that I can save the response data into session storage, but I don't know of any way to access the response.

What's the standard for designing a login page? What am I missing? Is it not standard to use an html form for this? And if so, what do I do about sessions?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use the browser's session storage for this, because the user can manipulate this. All security-related information should be on the server.

Comment: So you should be using server-side session storage (e.g. `$_SESSION` in PHP), not the browser's `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't totally get it, if you store session the session ID on the server only, how do you know which requests belong to which session. My thought was that the client holds onto the sessionID and sends to the server with each request so that the server knows who sent the request.

Comment: The server uses a cookie to link the browser session with the server-side session data. This is handled automatically for you by the middleware.